# PHP Регулярное выражение нежадное

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите закончить регулярное выражение. Имеется строка, в которой первую найденную букву необходимо перевести в верхний регистр, делаю так:

```
$str = 'james jimmy smith';
echo preg_replace_callback('/([[:alpha:]])/Uu', function ($matches) {return strtoupper($matches[0]);}, $str);
```

Но выражение выполняется "жадно" и поднимает все символы строки в верхний регистр, вот так: `JAMES JIMMY SMITH` а нужно так: `James jimmy smith` Модификатор /U не помогает. `ucfirst()` не подходит, потому что строка может начинаться не с буквы.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В первую группу захватите первую букву, во вторую все остальные символы до конца строки:

```
<?php

  $str = '111 привет james jimmy smith';

  echo preg_replace_callback('/([[:alpha:]])([\s\S]*)/u', function ($matches) {   
    return mb_strtoupper($matches[1], 'UTF-8') . $matches[2];
  }, $str);

?>
```

[Демо здесь](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7132778f27bcdb347d798ca587ea357fe276022e).